# Objective-C's UIView and animationIDs

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview

What are all the valid animationID strings for the `beginAnimations::` class method on `UIView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animationID is any string you decide to use. It's for identifying the animation in the animations's willStart and didStop delegate methods.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW14):

> *animationID* Application-supplied
>   identifier for the animations within a
>   block that is passed to the animation
>   delegate messages—the selectors set
>   using the
>   setAnimationWillStartSelector: and
>   setAnimationDidStopSelector: methods.